# Did Grothendieck acknowledge his collaborators' intellectual contributions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, math-history

Pierre Cartier's [account](http://inference-review.com/article/a-country-known-only-by-name/) of Alexander Grothendieck's life and work includes an interesting reflection from Grothendieck on his time in the IHES seminar:

> In a moment of true lucidity, he (Grothendieck) said something like, “I was the only person to have the breath of inspiration, and what I transmitted to those around me wasn’t inspiration, but a job. I had workmen around me, but none of them really had inspiration!”

Many of Grothendieck's collaborators, especially Serre, are considered among the greatest mathematicians of the 20th century.  Serre was known for his own significant contributions to algebraic geometry in the 1950s.  Did Grothendieck's collaborators really bring so little to the development of modern algebraic geometry?  And did Grothendieck ever acknowledge any of his collaborators as his equal?

Comment: Read Grothendieck's correspondence with Serre and others.

Comment: I don't think that Serre was that much of a "collaborator" for Grothendieck. He was more like a very inspiring teacher (in the best sense of the word), but he soon stopped taking active interest in Grothendieck's reworking of algebraic geometry. Essentially, this reworking is a continuation of FAC (as Gr. himself acknowledged, but it became too general and abstract for Serre, who wasn't interested in what Grothendieck wanted to achieve. For example, he didn't listen to Grothendieck when he talked about derived categories and the general formalism of duality: he developed those by himself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) I had begun writing a long answer but I found that analysing  the thousand page paranoid rant "Récoltes et Semailles" too depressing.

2) Summing-up: the scandalous calumnies and accusations of plagiarism  of Grothendieck toward  mathematicians like Deligne, Illusie, Kashiwara, Kawai, Serre and many others would be unforgivable if it weren't for the tragic circumastances of Grothendieck's youth, who had to hide as a child in order not be murdered in Auschwitz like his father.

3) As to the actual question: Grothendieck is undoubtedly one of the greatest mathematicians of all times and his extraordinary creations and prophetic visions  attracted some of the best mathematicians on earth to his seminars between 1955 and 1970 (roughly).
These mathematicians profited immensely from Grothendieck's genius, but the converse is also true.
Mike Artin made  great contributions to étale cohomology and Demazure, Illusie, Oort, Hartshorne, Manin, Mumford, Murre, Raynaud, Verdier,... had many profound and creative insights which I can't go into for lack of space and above all competence.
Grothendieck apparently couldn't/wouldn't write down his mathematics and the thousands of pages we can read about his *oeuvre* are the result of the dedication of his volunteer scribes.
In the same vein, [the prenotes to Part V of EGA](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/EGA/EGA5.pdf) show what EGA would have become  without Dieudonné's heroic efforts to clean up the preliminary manuscripts of Grothendieck.
In conclusion, Grothendieck certainly gave a vital impulsion to the renewal of algebraic geometry in the late 50's and 60's, but that field has flowered thanks to the collaborative creativity of incredibly talented young (at the time) mathematicians, none of whom can be dismissed in Grothendieck's scornful way.

Comment: A digression about (2) : denote $X$ the set of people having suffered the same circumstances as Grothendieck's in his youth. Denote $X'$ the subset of $X$ consisting in people having commited scandalous actions, that somehow confine to *madness*. Both sets are finite for obvious reasons and the cardinal of $X'$ is really neglectible compared to the cardinal of $X$, *so that* you can't logically attribute these actions to having suffered these conditions, albeit horrible.

Comment: What one should do imo is try to explain *from inside* these accusations etc, that is, by finding other motives in Grothendieck's personality, proper to him. Not by outside, in a *sociological* manner. "He's mugging old ladies in the street for money. That's because he is poor", says the sociologist. I beg to differ : only an epsilonesque proportion of poor people are mugging old ladies for money, so that underpriviledge is not an explaining factor.

Comment: About (2), properly this time, and I obvioulsy won't name people : a student (having firmly contributed to SGA) of Grothendieck once told me about another student of Grothenieck (this one not having contributed to EGA/SGA) that the latter had "stolen" many ideas from Grothendieck's student to made them his own ideas. What's fun is that this latter student is the one that Grothendieck cherishes in *Récoltes et Semailles*.

Comment: @Olórin why can't you tell who is that supposed student who stole Grothendieck's ideas? Don't you think it should be pointed out to denounce plagiarism? You don't have to say who told this to you. BTW, I read Recoltes et Semailles and can't recall a single student "cherished" by Grothendieck's, except possibly Contou-Carrere and Olivier Leroy, but IMO those post1970 students don't count

Comment: Because mathematical research is quite an hypocritical domain (not more nor less than other domains though) where people don't like to name people. And also you could find the name yourself in Récoltes et semailles, would you read it properly.

Comment: And the name is also in my answer. :)

Comment: @Olórin you are obviously talking about Mebkhout, then, but he wasn't a "student of Grothendieck" in the proper sense. He started his thesis when Groth was no longer in IHÉS, under Verdier's distant direction (and help from other mathematicians, Houzel, Ruget, Ramis IIRC). Your comment doesn't make any sense given that: 1) he wasn't G's student and 2) he apparently gave credit to Grothendieck where it was due (but not to Kashiwara, which is dirty, but the situation seems to hace changed now, and he gives ref to Kashiwara).

Comment: In the proper sense. I see.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to George's (1), I would say that if you dig in the indeed depressing *[Récoltes et semailles](https://www.quarante-deux.org/archives/klein/prefaces/Romans_1965-1969/Recoltes_et_semailles.pdf)* you'll find severe hints towards a huge author's paranoïa (implying that one has to be cautious about taking for granted everything that is written there) and a profound respect for mainly three people :

- Jean-Pierre Serre (called a "detonator" for Grothendieck's ideas, mainly through their long correspondance)
- Pierre Deligne (for instance "*Deligne avait été un peu élève de Tits (en Belgique) - je doute qu’il ait été élève de quelqu’un en mathématique, au sens
  courant du terme*", or "*Mon rôle mathématique auprès de Deligne s’est borné à le mettre au courant, à la petite semaine, du peu que je savais en
  géométrie algébrique, qu’il a appris comme on écoute un conte - comme s’il l’avait toujours su ; et chemin faisant aussi, à
  soulever des questions auxquelles le plus souvent il trouvait réponse, sur le champ ou dans les jours suivants*")
- Zoghman Mebkhout (for whom the respect is quite tainted with pity, especially because Grothendieck blames him for having indulged his own "victim" condition)

I feel that Grothendieck had even more, way more, respect for Deligne than he had for Serre, which explains why he coined Deligne "principal master of the ceremony of the burial of Grothendieck's ideas" in Récoltes et semailles and why so much hatred and disappointment is felt from Grothendieck about him, and why so much obsession with him emanates from this book.